# Simple control/component for selecting group of strings (labels)

Tags: java, swt

I need some swt component, which I can use to select/unselect a group of strings.
I need a structure similar to this one,
https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Checkboxgroup

The above mentioned solution is however an overkill for my requirements. 
I was wondering if I could achieve the same functionality using any other swt-components.
(for example if a tree allowed only root-level selection rather than at the child-level, it would be the best for me)

Comment: Why the `swt-awt` tag? And what's overkill about the `Checkboxgroup`? Please elaborate what exactly it is you need and how `Checkboxgroup` isn't a good fit to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. 
swt-awt tag was probably wrong. I took it off.<br/>
<br/>
The 'CheckboxGroup' in that link is misleading. It is actually a 'Group' with a checkbox. So when you check it, all its contents are selected.

Let's say there are two groups of Strings,<br/>
-Group A<br/>
--A1<br/>
--A2<br/>
-Group B<br/>
--B1<br/>
--B2<br/>

If I implement this using tree, it allows selecting A1/A2 and B1/B2 individually.<br/>
<br/>
I need some swt component which would allow selecting Group A, Group B but not A1/A2 and B1/B2 individually.

Comment: I apologize for the improper formatting in the above comment..
It's my first time here, and I'm just getting started.
The site won't allow me to fix it, i.e. edit comments after 5 mins (didn't know that).

Comment: Don't try and put code or diagrams in comments, instead edit your question and add more detail there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is an example without a `Tree`. It uses a `Composite` to hold a `Button` and another `Composite` that holds `Label`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    MyGroup first = new MyGroup(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    first.setHeader("A");
    first.addStrings("A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1", "A2 A2 A2 A2 A2 A2", "A3 A3 A3 A3");

    MyGroup second = new MyGroup(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    second.setHeader("B");
    second.addStrings("B1", "B2");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class MyGroup extends Composite
{
    private Button      button;
    private Composite   content;

    public MyGroup(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        button = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
        content = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginLeft = 20;

        content.setLayout(layout);
        content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    public void setHeader(String header)
    {
        button.setText(header);
    }

    public void addStrings(String... strings)
    {
        for (String string : strings)
            new Label(content, SWT.NONE).setText(string);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I did think about using tree, and setting data only for child items. But, I don't want the user to see checkboxes at all, for child items. It just adds to confusion from UI perspective. If I could disable (don't show at all) the checkboxes for child items (if tree allowed different styles for different items) I would use it.. but it does not. That's the reason why I can't use tree, and looking for a different component / set of components that can be used.

Comment: @mike_kc_2014 Then you'll probably have to write your own `Widget` based on a `Button` with `SWT.CHECK` (the checkbox) and then a `List` or a `Composite` with `Label`s for your sub-items. Or something similar.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks..
Yup, I ended up using the checkBox followed by a List of Labels.

Comment: @mike_kc_2014 I've updated my answer with some code.